# How to map data based on substring?

Tags: text-processing

I have data in the following manner:

```
staging_uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb
staging_uw_pc_account_hive_tb
staging_uw_pc_account_location_hive_tb
uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb
uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb_backup
uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb
uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb_backup
```

How do I create a map based on the following rules?

1. remove `_backup` from the end
2. remove `staging_` from the start
3. and now check the mapping.

The result should be something like this. Not every table should have staging and backup in that case those fields should be empty.

```
uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb, uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb_backup, staging_uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb
```

Comment: What will you do about name collisions? E.g. `uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb` and `uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb_backup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `awk` script would detect the presence of the `staging_` prefix and/or the `_backup` suffix on each line of input.

The prefix and suffix are removed if they exist, and the remaining string is used as a key in an associative array called `map`.

The original line is saved in the `map` array, in a comma-delimited string associated with the generated key.

At the end, all the entires of `map` are printed.

```c
BEGIN {
        OFS = ", "
        prefix = "staging_"
        suffix = "_backup"
}

{
        key = $0
        sub("^" prefix, "", key)
        sub(suffix "$", "", key)

        map[key] = (map[key] == "" ? $0 : map[key] OFS $0)
}

END {
        for (key in map) print map[key]
}
```

Test run with the data from the question in the file called `file`:

```bsh
$ awk -f script file
staging_uw_pc_account_location_hive_tb
staging_uw_pc_account_hive_tb
uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb, uw_pc_account_contact_hive_tb_backup
staging_uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb, uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb, uw_pc_account_contact_role_hive_tb_backup
```

The ordering of the fields within the individual lines of output is determined by the ordering of the lines in the original file.